# Define a custom input type with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Is it possible to define a custom input type with jQuery or pure JavaScript? Let's say that I'd like to have an input which looks something like this:

```
<input type="data-rnd">
```

If it *is* possible, where and how would I tell the browser how to render it / what to do with it?

The type itself would be a duplicate of `type="hidden"`. One of the main reasons for this is obscurity.

Comment: It is possible but you need to give more information about what you are trying to do in order to get a proper answer.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis Well, I thought it would be a way to somewhat obscure what the field is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can add a CSS selector

```
input[type="data-rnd"]
```

and define your own css to it. This is css2 selection, it is widely supported by browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)

I'm not sure you mean this, but this can be helpful.

Comment: Hm, interesting that it's just pure CSS. Don't know why, but FireFox wasn't displaying anything related to the element. After checking Chrome, I can see that the style for input and its various types is defined by user agent. Thanks!